# Add prefix to XML Root Node - Implementation of Scott Hanselman's suggestion?

Tags: xml, web-services, xml-serialization, soap-extension

I would like to add a namespace prefix to the XML root node and I found an entry by Scott Hanselman which details exactly what I would like to achieve. The only problem being the implementation is missing !

[Modifying the namespace PREFIX of the root node of the body of a SOAP Web Services Response....whew!](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/XmlRootForcePrefixPrefixfoo.aspx)

It would be of great help if I could get a few leads on how to go about this.

1. Is there an implementation that already exists somewhere ?
2. The entry by Scott was posted in 2003. Have things changed since then ? With .NET 3.5 around, are Soap Extensions still the right approach ?

EDIT:
Current Web Service Response is something like ...

```
<response>
   <my-ns:name/>
</response>
```

desired response should look like ...

```
<my-ns:response>
   <my-ns:name/>
</my-ns:response>
```

Comment: Scott does say: > If you want the code, and to go to
> hell, email me [Here](http://2idi.com/contact/=scott.hanselman), that's probably the best route if no-one has any ideas.

Comment: Please say what you're trying to accomplish. Why does the prefix matter? Also, I don't think SoapExtensions were necessary to begin with - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlnamespacedeclarationsattribute.aspx.

Comment: @John, The prefix does not and should not matter, but it is a "client" requirement which one has to meet. If you read the Scott's entry, that is precisely what he mentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the issue with the missing namespace prefix for the root node exists only on .NET Framework 1.1 !

I migrated the code to .NET 3.5 and the **"my-ns:"** namespace prefix was added to the root node without me having to modify any code ! So I wouldn't have to write a Soap Extension  after all !

Comment: Did you happen to try it out in .NET 2.0 ?

Comment: No not 2.0, I tried 3.5 ! But I suppose it should, considering that you too got the prefix in the root node.

Comment: There are code attributes for specifying the namespace of the response element.